# react router takes two click to update the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have used react-router v4 for routing in my application. I have used routing to show various form like for showing apartment form, experience form, login, register etc.

**Problem**

When i click on apartment image, react router routes to apartment form. The route becomes /apartment. If i again then click on register button, the route do not get updated. I have to double click on register button to update the route to /register.

**Here is my code**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log('context', context);
    this.state = { show: false };
  }

  showModal(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Nav
            showModal={(e) => this.showModal(e)}
            hideModal={() => this.hideModal()}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={() => this.hideModal()}
          />
        </div>
        );
  }
}

App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};



const Nav = (props) => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="">
              <img
                alt="Brand"
                className="img-responsive"
                src={logo}
                role="presentation"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-1">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-social-icon">
              <li className="dropdown">
                <a
                  href=""
                  className="dropdown-toggle"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                >
                  ES
                  <span className="caret" />
                </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu" style={{ color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                  <li onClick={() => props.selectedLocale('en')}>
                    en
                  </li>
                  <li onClick={() => props.selectedLocale('es')}>
                    es
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li className="btn-group regLog">
                <button
                  className="btn btn-default"
                  onClick={props.showModal}
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/signup' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
                <button
                  onClick={props.showModal}
                  className="btn btn-default"
                >
                  <Link to={{ pathname: '/login' }}>
                    {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.login.text' }) }
                  </Link>
                </button>
                {props.show ?
                  <ModalForm
                    show={props.show}
                    onHide={props.onHide}
                  /> : <span />
                }
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </Router>
  );


class ModalForm extends Component {
  render() {
    const { show, onHide, intl } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router>
        <Modal
          {...this.props}
          show={show}
          onHide={onHide}
          dialogClassName="custom-modal"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Link to='/login' className="logTitle">
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.login.text' })}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Link>
            <Link to='/signup' className="logTitle">
              <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-lg">
                {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'nav.registration.text' })}
              </Modal.Title>
            </Link>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Match pattern='/login' component={Login} />
            <Match pattern='/signup' component={Signup} />
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I think its because of using onClick event and routing. How can i solve it?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use router context but i am getting `undefined`. App is a parent component and Nav is a child component. Nav component uses router while onClick functions are handled in App component where this.context.router has to be handled.

Thanks

Comment: Which onClick event do you think is the issue? Also, where is the code for the /register route, I can't see it in your sample, did you mean the signup route?

Comment: my bad, its a /signup route.

Comment: I have updated my question. showModal is resposible for showing form in modal but my modal has two form, one for signup and one for login. So when register is clicked, a form of register should be shown in modal but if login is clicked, login form should be shown in modal.

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirect on onClick function using router context ...

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#routercontext

You use `contextTypes` from `react` to access `router` from `react-router` and the n use push to change url

Comment: I have updated my question. I tried to use router context but getting undefined. You can see App is my parent component and Nav is child component.

Comment: You made half of changes ... where is this.context.router.push()???? this call changes the url to where you want to go... so you can remove Link...

Comment: I am getting undefined while consoling in the constructor of App component.

Comment: I dont know why i still get undefined in my case.

Comment: hummm.. sorry I think it's because you're using v4.... it is alpha right? and probably changes how this works...

Answer (score 0):

I am also using RRv4, to handle button links as you have then I wrap the `button` in the `link`. The put the overall click handler on the link. This should call prior to the transition and if you need to prevent transition you can simply call `e.preventDefault`

This will maintain the declarative nature of RRv4 and prevent the need to use the experimental `context` feature in react.